# Как проверить существование записи в MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД (book) в которой есть столбец "name". Как поставить условие, что бы перед тем, как программа заполняла БД она проверяла существование таблицы с таким "name"?

Всем спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот попробуйте:

- `mysql_list_tables` — возвращает список таблиц базы данных MySQL
- `mysql_list_tables ( string $database [, resource $link_identifier] )`
  первый обязательный параметр - база данных, с которой работаете. В  вашем случае - это book.

После обрабатываешь результат с помощью цикла:

```
<?php $exists=false;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {
        if($row=="name"){$exists=true;break;}
    }
    if($exists){...}
?>
```

Это не единственное решение, так что может даже найдете и проще, или посложнее. Надеюсь, я правильно вас понял.

Answer (score 10):

```
if (mysql_query('DROP TABLE table')) {
    echo "Да, такая таблица действительно была...";
}
```

Прошу прощения, не удержался :)

Comment: Совет, конечно, вредоносный, но весёлый :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы имели в виду **таблица** а не *столбец*? Если да то так:

```
function mysql_table_seek($tablename, $dbname)
{
    $table_list = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM `".$dbname."`");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($table_list)) {
        if ($tablename==$row[0]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
} 
if(!mysql_table_seek($tablename, $dbname)){
   // Добавить запись
} else {
   // Добавить таблицу или просто вывести ошибку что таблицы нет.
}
```

**Добавлено (на комментарий).**

Для того чтобы незаморачиваться по этому поводу, в БД MySQL у id поставьте **auto_increment**, после чего ненужно будет вообще в поле id самостоятельно добавлять.
Вот ссылка на эту тему

http://mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html

Что-же касается остальных значений полей, то все тоже очень просто, для начала вы проверяете существует ли запись в таблице:

```
SELECT id FROM book WHERE name = 'Книга'
```

Если поле id не пустое, то уже существует, иначе добавим новую книгу.

**Добавлено (на комментарий).**

В таком случае вам подойдет проверка, о которой я написал выше.

*Пример:*

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM book WHERE name = 'Книга'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    echo "Записи до сих пор нет!"; 
}else{ 
    echo "Такая запись уже существует!"; 
}
```

Comment: Допустим, мне в базу данных нужно внести значения из след. переменных id, name, mail .
Перед тем, как это всё делать, нужно проверить чтобы во все БД не было такова же id и если его нет, то заполнять...

Comment: Дело в том, что в id передаётся из формы, которую пользователь заполняет. Да, и там будут находиться не только цифры.

Answer (score 0):

:) к дропу есть небольшое дополнение, человеку необходимо знать есть ли таблица в БД, о чем он пишет выше.. так что:

```
if (mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table`')){
    echo "Да, такая таблица действительно была...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM book WHERE name = 'Книга'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){ 
    echo "Записи до сих пор нет!"; 
}else{ 
    echo "Такая запись уже существует!"; 
}
```

> Как по мне, это само простое решение. Кстати, ее можно использовать
>   когда делаешь регистрацию - проверка, существует ли пользователь с
>   таким логином, или когда вход на сайт.